# Using CSV Helper to write a single record from a class

Tags: c#, export-to-csv, csvhelper

I am using the library CSV Helper found at https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/ to try and write a function that will export a class for me. Here is my example class:

```
 public class Z1000
{
    public string ModelNumber { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    private string InputVolts { get; set; }
    private string InputHz { get; set; }
    private string InputPhase { get; set; }
    private string InputAmps { get; set; }
    private string OutputVolts { get; set; }
    private string OutputHz { get; set; }
    private string OutputPhase { get; set; }
    private string OutputAmps { get; set; }
    private string Type { get; set; }
    private string WiringDiagram { get; set; }
    private string SCCR { get; set; }
    private string FLA { get; set; }
    private bool SuitableForUseAsServiceEquipment { get; set; } = false;
    private List<string> InstanceManuals { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    private List<string> Options { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    private List<Fuse> Fuses { get; set; } = new List<Fuse>();              
  }
```

This class has several functions as well, I excluded them as they are not important to the question. Here is the function I am trying to use to export a single record.

```
public void ExportToCsv<T>(T classToExport)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Data\Output.csv"))
        {
            var csv = new CsvWriter(writer);
            csv.WriteHeader(typeof(T));
            csv.WriteRecord(classToExport);
        }
    }
```

The code executes just fine but for some reason the csv file that gets exported is just empty. Am I missing some kind of step here? I have tried it several different ways and just can't seem to lock it down. I read the documentation for writing and their examples and none of it seems to work for me. Am I missing something entirely?

EDIT:
I put a break point and verified the public member data is being written.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this library requires you to flush a record after outputting it.

From the GitHub site: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/writing

> **Ending the Row**
>
> When you are done writing the row, you need to flush the fields and
>   start a new row. Flushing and starting a new row are separated so that
>   you can flush without creating a new row. Calling `NextRecord()` will
>   flush for you.

Comment: Yup! I just stumbled on the answer while testing the next record function. thank you!